# Laravel 5 package development - Auth::attempt() leads to App\User not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm developing a package that wraps some of the Laravel User logic, because i want to keep the native implementation while adding some feature to it.

This is my package's composer.json

```
{
    "name": "foo/bar",
    "description": "A Laravel 5 package",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "",
            "email": ""
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4.0",
        "illuminate/auth": "5.1.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "orchestra/testbench": "~3.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Foo\\": "src/Foo/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable"
}
```

This is a sample code:

```
class Foo {
    function login($username, $password) { 
        \Auth::attempt($username, $password);
    }
}
```

This is a sample test case

```
class UserServiceTest extends \Orchestra\Testbench\TestCase {
    function testLogin() {
        $foo = new Foo();
        $foo->login('foo', 'bar');
    }
}
```

Now, when running the test i get this `PHP Fatal error:  Class '\App\User' not found in path/to/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/EloquentUserProvider.php on line 126`

I can understand why (App\User lives in the `laravel/laravel` package), however i cannot understand how to properly declare my package dependencies.

What should i do in order to reuse the whole Auth and User laravel native implementation?

Comment: Start with declaring laravel/laravel as your dependency, otherwise the \App\User class just doesn't exist.

Comment: Another thing is that laravel/laravel is a base application and it doesn't make sense to include that if User class is the only thing you need. Add a user class to your package or just assume that any app that will use your package will have their own User class - most will.

Comment: I know, but that can't be the only solution - adding the whole laravel app as a dependency to develop a laravel package seems to be little weird.

Comment: It is, but if you want to use a class form a package you need to add that package as a dependency, right? That's why I suggested you implmeneted user class yourself

Comment: That won't solve anyway i think, siince EloquentUserProvider is tightly coupled with App\User. So i should write another class and namespace it to App\User - that will trigger autoloading issues for sure

Comment: Eloquent user provider is not coupled at all. It gets the model name as a parameter to its constructor

Comment: Thank you mate, your last reply helped me clarify. Feel free to post an answer and i'll be glad to accept. Cheers

Comment: I added some more explanation in the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use **laravel/laravel** package in order to reuse Laravel's authentication.

It's enough to just import **illuminate/auth** package. This will give you 2 out of 3 things that you need to authenticate users:

- **Guard** class (usually accessed via **Auth** facade) that provides authentication method (attempt, check, etc.)
- **User provider** that fetches users based on their credentials - this package provides both Eloquent and Database user provider

The last thing you need is a User class, or any Model that implements **AuthenticatableContract**.

**Guard** takes **user provider** as one of its constructor's arguments, and **user provider** takes the class of a model to use as one of its constructor's arguments.

Those 3 elements are enough to use Laravel's authentication.

Comment: Please look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60145798/why-laravel-6-auth-returns-false-after-redirecting-by-using-custom-guard