# Package development - auth check doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, package, laravel-5.3

I have made a simple fresh Laravel 5.3 app for the purpose of developing a package. I have followed instructions from [here](http://laraveldaily.com/how-to-create-a-laravel-5-package-in-10-easy-steps/#comment-16080) and some modifications made in comments by user named Janis. Everything works perfectly.

Then I decided to upgrade the published view with

```
@if(Auth::check())
    ID: {{Auth::id()}}.
@else
    not logged in
@endif
```

The current state of the app is uploaded to Github [here](https://github.com/UnrulyNatives/laravel-package-playground).

### Problem

The view the check doesn't work. I always have the `not logged in`.
How to make the `Auth::check()` work?
In another tab of my browser I am logged correclty.

### A hint

I am not sure how to follow [this hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31793183/laravel-5-package-development-authattempt-leads-to-app-user-not-found)

### To do

Please instruct me how to make the `Auth::check()` work in the view.

Comment: What happend if you make dd(Auth::check()) in the package controller which loads that view?

Comment: I just get `false` on blank page

Comment: You are saying it works fine in another tab of your browser - how is that possible? What do you mean by 'on this side'?

Comment: Have you tried to check if you are really being logged in? Try dumping `Auth::user()` after logging in successfully.

Comment: For me it looks impossible too. Try to start the app on your local machine to see for yourself. I have edited out the `On this side`. It meant that from the perspective of the original app, everything seems to work fine.

Comment: Ok, im just trying to follow the hint. Add at the top of your view controller "use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth" then, log into your app once again then dd(Auth::check()). Still getting false?

Comment: @Doom5 Yes - on the welcome page everything is fine. I can log in and log out - and the state of Auth::check() changes accordingly.

Comment: @JulianRodriguez I added. Before I added just `use Auth;` as in the HomeController. Doesn't work. Laravel hates me, I guess.

Comment: Ok, this is my last idea. I hope this work, Checking the totorial (I followed it once some time ago but not used auth at all) found that the route does not use any middleware. I suggest you to enforce your package router to use the web middleware, then check again the dd(Auth::check())

Comment: @JulianRodriguez A last idea tends to be the right one. That was it. Please publish your suggestion as an answer! Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Laravel 5, any route in routes.php automatically uses the web middleware, but this does not happend with your packages routes.

To use Laravel's authentication into your package controllers and views you need to enforce the web middleware usage in to your package route.php using something like:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
  // your package routes here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well try this artisan command

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

Comment: I tried before posting this question. I wish I'd be that easy. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is my structure for my package's routes in my service provider.

the only thing you have to do is, adding 'web' middleware for your routes

```
$routeConfig = [
        'namespace' => config('banasher.controllers.namespace')."\Panel",
        'prefix'    => 'panel',
        'as'        => 'panel.',
        //TODO: add middleware
        'middleware' => ['web','auth']
    ];
    $this->getRouter()->group($routeConfig, function() {
        require __DIR__.'\routes\banasher.php';
    });
```