# Why laravel 6 auth returns false after redirecting by using custom guard?

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to make auth through laravel package using admins table. In the project directory I added admin guard into config/auth.php

```
'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],

        'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Admin::class,
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],
```

And in the guard array

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => false,
    ],

    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],
    ],
```

Following is my login controller inside pacakge

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{

   use AuthenticatesUsers;
   protected $redirectTo = '/admin/dashboard';
   protected function redirectTo()
   {
         return '/admin/dashboard';
   }

   public function __construct()
   {
       $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
   }
   public function login(Request $request)
   {   
       if(Auth::guard('admin')->attempt($request->only('email','password'), true)){
           return redirect()
               ->intended(route('dashboard'))
               ->with('status','You are Logged in as Admin!');
       }
   }

}
```

and following is my dashboard controller

```
class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        /* dd(Auth::check()); */ //return false : just want to show you

          $this->middleware('auth:admin');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return view('xyz::dashboard');
    }

}
```

And in my Admin.php Model following script is there

```
namespace App;

class Admin extends \ABC\xyz\App\Models\Admin
{

}

Which is extending package model

namespace ABC\xyz\App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
class Admin extends Authenticatable
{

    protected $table = 'admins';
}
```

And below are the routes from my package

```
    $namespace = 'ABC\Xyz\App\Http\Controllers';
    Route::group([    
    'namespace' => $namespace,
    'middleware' => ['web'], 
    'prefix' => 'admin'
], function () {
    Route::get('login', function(){
        return view('xyz::auth.login');
    })->name('login');

    Route::post('/login', 'Auth\LoginController@login')->name('customLogin');
});

Route::group(['namespace' => $namespace,'prefix' => 'admin',  'middleware' => ['auth']  ], function () {
    Route::get('dashboard', 'DashboardController@index')->name('dashboard');
});
```

When I try to login, after submitting valid details it does not redirecting me to dashboard, nothing happening. Also when I try for open forcefully /dashboard it take me to login page.

Also right after login attempt when I try `Auth::check()` it's returns true but same thing returning false in `dashboardController.php` construct function. In the same way `Auth::guard('admin')->user()` returns user's info while on `dashboardController.php` it's returns null.

**Strange Result of php artisan route:list**

As you can see in `DashboardController.php` construct I added `$this->middleware('auth:admin');`

So when I try to add `dd(Auth::guard('admin')->user())` and then check in terminal `php artisan route:list` it returns null and sometime false, any idea why it is happening?

I don't know what and where I am missing something.

I would like to request you kindly guide me about it. I would appreciate.

Thank you

Comment: You must have defined the `admin guard` in the admin model otherwise, no admin will be authenticated

Comment: @Johhn you mean like this `protected $guard = 'admin';`

Comment: yes absolutely `protected $guard = 'admin'; `

Comment: are you using custom primary key ?

Comment: @Nandakumar the primary key is `id`

Comment: then try adding 'web' middle ware to this code
Route::group(['namespace' => $namespace,'prefix' => 'admin',  'middleware' => ['web', 'auth']  ], function () {
    Route::get('dashboard', 'DashboardController@index')->name('dashboard');
}); and clear all the cache

Comment: @Nandakumar I just tried, it giving me same result as I was getting before

Comment: Give modal a custom primary key!  id might causing problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in your routes file:

```
Route::group(['namespace' => $namespace,'prefix' => 'admin',  'middleware' => ['auth']  ], function () {
    Route::get('dashboard', 'DashboardController@index')->name('dashboard');
});
```

You are using the default guard with `auth` middleware. After you are logged in with `admin` guard you may not be logged in by your default `web` guard. That is why it fails and tries to redirect you to login page:

> When I try to login, after submitting valid details it does not redirecting me to dashboard, nothing happening. Also when I try for open forcefully /dashboard it take me to login page.

Instead, you should specify in your group that you are using the `admin` guard:

```
Route::group(['namespace' => $namespace,'prefix' => 'admin',  'middleware' => ['auth:admin']], function () {
    Route::get('dashboard', 'DashboardController@index')->name('dashboard');
});
```

However, you already specified in your `DashboardController` to use `$this->middleware('auth:admin');`, so there is no need to specifiy it in the route group again. The following is enough and reduces the likelihood to create an error:

```
Route::group(['namespace' => $namespace,'prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
    Route::get('dashboard', 'DashboardController@index')->name('dashboard');
});
```

Comment: I appreciate your time and followed your instructions but still session does not passing to `dashboardController.php` when I try `$this->middleware('auth:admin');
        dd(Auth::guard('admin')->check());` in construct function it returns `false` however in `login()` it returns `true`. It is so strange. May be because of package ?

Comment: @ImranAbbas this is normal behavior. If you call `Auth::guard('admin')->check()` in the constructor of your controller it will always return false. This is, because the controller may be added to the service container before authentication is working. You may find more about it here: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/lifecycle
However, redirect to dashboard should now work as expected, I guess?

Comment: @ImranAbbas try to add `dd(Auth::guard('admin')->check());` to your `index()` method of `DashboardController` and it will return true (it has to be removed from constructor method though)

Comment: bro if I remove `dd()` in construct it does not letting me in `index()`, it is redirecting back to `localhost:8000/login`

Comment: @ImranAbbas What happens if you add a new route and try to access it like this:    `Route::get('dashboardtest', 'DashboardController@index');` . Does `youdomain.dev/dashboardtest` work or is it also redirecting you?

Comment: @ImranAbbas if it is still redirecting you, try to remove `middleware` from constructor and check `dd(Auth::guard('admin')->check());` in your `index()` method.

Comment: Yes I just tried it is also redirecting me back to login

Comment: I just checked, yes it is returning `false` in `index()` method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207658/discussion-between-adam-and-imran-abbas).

Answer (score 0):

An extraction sample of the how you should define your admin model:

```
 // app/Admin.php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Admin extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $guard = 'admin';

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

For more on multiple authentications guards see: [How to use multiple authentication guards](https://pusher.com/tutorials/multiple-authentication-guards-laravel)

Comment: I just tried it does not working, still I am getting nothing in `Dashboard's Controller`

Answer (score 0):

Auth::guard('admin')->attempt($request->only('email','password') its returning true or false? If returning false then maybe toy didnt hashed your password
Try add this in your Model

```
 public function setPasswordAttribute($password)
    {
        $this->attributes['password'] = Hash::make($password);
    }
```

Comment: I am using `bcrypt()` function

Comment: That will also work  

Auth::guard('admin')->attempt($request->only('email','password') its returning true then?

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the Auth::check doesn't work on construct. this is because the middleware hasn't run yet, so Auth::check() should return false or null when you try to check in construct.

In your login controller, why are you using two redirectto?

```
   protected $redirectTo = '/admin/dashboard';
   protected function redirectTo()
   {
     return '/admin/dashboard';
   }
```

it is better to stick with one :-)

inside your Admin.php , add this:

```
protected $guard = 'admin';
```

for your web.php routes, replace

```
Route::group(['namespace' => $namespace,'prefix' => 'admin',  'middleware' => ['auth']  ], function () {
Route::get('dashboard', 'DashboardController@index')->name('dashboard');
});
```

with

```
Route::group(['namespace' => $namespace,'prefix' => 'admin',  'middleware' => ['auth:admin']  ], function () {
Route::get('dashboard', 'DashboardController@index')->name('dashboard');
});
```

finally, in DashboardController.php

replace the

```
        /* dd(Auth::check()); */ //return false : just want to show you
```

With:

```
    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
        dd(Auth::check());  //return false : just want to show you
        die;    
    });
```

Auth::check() should return true!

Comment: After using your instructions I can't access `DashboardController's` constructor

Comment: I know. remove the die;

Comment: I did same thing and but it does not allowing me to enter `DashboardController's` constructor as we added `auth:admin` in the route